# How can I fix the error "The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release"?

Tags: debian, package-management

After an upgrade from Debian Squeeze (stable) to Wheezy (testing), Synaptic fails with the following error:

```
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

However, this value is set nowhere in `/etc`. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look into `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf`. Look for the `DefaultDistro` line and change its value, e.g. replace `stable` with `wheezy`.

Answer (score 10):

I get the same error with apt, so it's unrelated to synaptic. However, this config exists:

```
# grep -ri stable /etc
/etc/apt.conf.d/99myDefaultRelease:APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

So changing that file to "jessie" would fix it in my case (as I'm on jessie.)

Comment: this one solved my problem in my raspberry pie 3 :D

Comment: Thanks, solved same problem on Debian

Comment: In my particular case it happened when switching from stable to testing, so "testing" works too.

Answer (score 2):

Even I was getting the same error, While I was updating my kali linux using `apt-get update` This is what I did and it worked for me.

`grep -ri stable /etc`

(some of you might get *stable*, *testing*, or *rolling* in the error message. Just replace that keyword in the above command and fire it)

I got a list of paths to files that used a *stable* keyword. after having a closer look I found this path.

*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local:APT::Default-Release "stable";*

I removed this file using `rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local` and tried updating and it worked.

For **However, this value is set nowhere in /etc. How do I fix this error?**
Maybe you should try the above steps in other directories too. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error

> E: The value 'testing' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

(or `stable` or whatever) is likely due to a mismatch between `/etc/apt` or `/etc/synaptic` configuration files (in particular the `sources.list` file).

Make sure you use the same version name everywhere.  E.g. make a choice between `testing` and `trixie` (or `wheezy` at the time the question was asked), or between `stable` and `bookworm`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

> E: The value 'jammy-infra-security' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
> E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

The synaptic.cfg which has this near the bottom of the file, DefaultDistro,
mine had this in list Synaptic:

```
:DefaultDistro "jammy-infra-security";
```

Open root, edit the "jammy-infra-security" remove infra, save file and reload Synaptic. My synaptic ran after this, without errors.